# Multiprocessing doesn't run on all CPU cores

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a parallel processing in Python which read data from a database, do some manipulation and run the Dijkstra algorithm:

```
t1 = 200101
t2 = 200229
import psutil
from multiprocess import Pool
pool = Pool(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
def graph_analysis(i):
    input_date = str(i)
    sql_data = """select trim(cast(p.Barcode as nvarchar(20))) Barcode ,cast(s.invoiceid as 
    nvarchar(20)) invoiceid
    from sales s inner join Product_981115 p on s.productid = p.productid 
    where s.date = """+ input_date +""" and s.qty != 0 and p.sectionid != 1691.199 and s.RegionID = """ + input_region
    data = [] 
    for chunk in pd.read_sql(sql_data,conn,chunksize = 1000000):
         data.append(chunk)
    data = pd.concat(data, ignore_index = True)
    data = data.merge(candid_sale_invoices)
    data = data.merge(candid_barcodes)
    final_edges_df = data.iloc[:,[2,3,4]]
    final_edges_tuples = [tuple(x) for x in final_edges_df.values]

    Gm = ig.Graph.TupleList(final_edges_tuples, directed = True, edge_attrs = ['weight'])

    longest_paths = pd.DataFrame(Gm.shortest_paths_dijkstra(None,None, weights = 'weight'))
    longest_paths = longest_paths.swifter.apply(log_transform)
    longest_paths["Date"] = input_date
    longest_paths["RegionID"] = input_region
    Return longest_paths

results = pool.map(graph_analysis,range(t1,(t2) + 1)))
pool.close()
results= pd.concat(results, ignore_index = True)
```

I ran this code a couple of days ago and it perfectly completed in parallel, utilizing almost all cores. However when I run it today, it seems that I have generated parallel processes but the cores doesn't process in parallel.
[image]

The system has 128 GB RAM and 32 Cores and nothing changed in it since the last successful parallel run. 
I restarted the system to solve any probable issue but the problem still exists.
So what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you data change and somehow it calculate in short window time and then complete? so you dont notice it? Just want to make sure, Since from your picture, I could see it still spawn a lot of python process

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong The number of iterations has increased. Last time the range had 45 iterations, now it has 60 iterations...however the structure of data and the computations remains the same.

Comment: One more quick question, does it complete much slower, or you just want to know why your cpu does not goes up?

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong I terminated the run, cause it seemed that the cores doesn't process anything.

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong with 45 iterations, the cpu goes up in no time...however with 60 iterations after almost 10 minutes nothing changed. so I terminated the process.